# How do I insulate my Laddomat 21 boiler charger?

Tags: insulation, boiler

I have a mixing device [Laddomat 21](http://www.laddomat.eu/index.php?sida=produkter&undersida=laddomat&produkt=laddomat_21&lang=en) installed for my boiler + accumulator tank. I have all pipes around the boiler insulated with pre-formed moulded mineral wool insulation, but there is no insulation on the Laddomat unit. As the unit is quite hot (70-90 deg.C) and its metalic area quite large, I assume the thermal loss on it can be substantial. For newer/large models the manufacturer is selling a ready to use insulation from EPP (see [image](http://www.laddomat.eu/index.php?sida=produkter&undersida=laddomat&produkt=laddomat_21-60&lang=en)), but there is none available for this type.

How could I make a DIY insulation for it? If possible, the insulation should be possible to take apart if some service is needed on the Laddomat.

Comment: Consult with the manufacturer before you make any changes to this device.  If it's already operating at temperatures close to boiling, it may depend on its ability to dissipate heat, and causing it to retain heat may potentially damage parts inside.

Comment: I do not intend to change it, only to wrap the insulation around it. No, it does not need to dissipate heat, it is a mixer or radiator / boiler water. I have consulted it with the manufacturer, their reply was they are not producing the insulation for this model, they are producing it for "higher" models only (the insulation is a two part EPP box, as seen on the picture).

Comment: Sorry I did miss that bit - thats what I get for posting w/o enough coffee. :)

Answer (score 1):

They talk about using EPP-Insulation which is expanded polypropelyne foam:

> EPP is flexible foam that is used as a packing material for delicate electronic parts.  It is also used in the bumpers of some automobiles.  It is a rubbery material that is light in weight, yet very durable.

http://www.flyingfoam.com/FoamTypes.html

Based on that, I think you could do quite well with simply buying some basic pipe insulation
[image]

and do some creative wrapping of the insulation around the fitting, adhering it with duct tape (not directly to the device but insulation to insulation only).

Comment: I will think about it. I am also considering of getting some large EPP block and cutting the box from it on my own. However, with EPP I am a bit concerned about fire safety. The Laddomat is only 15 cm behind the boiler. Fire regulations require no "flammable" (A2, B, C, D class by EN 13501-1:2002) objects to be placed with 20 cm range and no "easily flammable" (E, F class) within 40 cm range. I guess EPP is most likely "flammable" (D class), but I am not sure, and I was unable to find a definitive answer.

Comment: I think perhaps "mineral wool slabs" might do (like http://www.isover.cz/en/orstech-110), however I am not sure how well it is possible to cut some more complicated shapes in it. They declare it can be cut with a knife, but they probably mean just a simple cutting. Did someone work with a material like this?